# Add a second role when registering programmatically

Tags: user-roles, user-registration

I would like to know if there is a way that at the time of submitting the registration the user programmatically add a second role, so he would have the default role and the second, is it possible?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use the [register_new_user](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/register_new_user/) hook which fires after the registration is complete. e.g.

```php
function add_role_to_new_user( $user_id ) {
    $new_user = get_userdata( $user_id );
    if ( $new_user ) {
        $new_user->add_role( 'a_second_role' );
    }
}
add_filter( 'register_new_user', 'add_role_to_new_user' );
```

This will - I think - fire for all new users, including new administrators added in the dashboard. If that's not what you want then you can add a check e.g. `in_array( 'subscriber', $new_user->roles, true )` first before adding the new role.

Comment: Hello,

Thank you for your reply, that's what I was looking for.
And exactly as you say I want only "subscribers" users to have a second role added.
But in fact when a user registers through a form, this can choose the role to which to register, so when you submit the registration form I guess it does not appear as the subscriber role but the role chosen by the user, right?
If so, what would be the modification in the code that you have passed me?

I hope I have explained.

Thank you